# How to get out of TWRP without touchscreen and functions

Tags: twrp, boot, lineageos

I am running LineageOS 18.1 on my Raspberry Pi 4 with 4 GB (using this ROM: `https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/LineageOS18/`). It worked, until I tried getting into TWRP to root the device. But, since TWRP is touch and I didn't knew this before, I got stuck since I have no touchscreen. Now, if I turn the device off and on again after a few seconds, it still boots into TWRP and asks me if I want to install it to /system. But how do I get into the normal Android mode again. And since the RPi4 has no buttons like Volume Up, Down and Power, I can't boot normally into the system. So how can I modify the files to get out of there or is there any other way to get out of TWRP without buying a touchscreen?

Comment: adb is enabled, use it

Comment: I could try that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found something interesting. I can't (somehow) connect to it via ADB, but I could connect the USB-C power cable to my laptop and could somehow control my mouse. Thanks to everybody who helped.